# combining insert statements

Tags: sql, oracle

How would I multiple insert statements together?  There's 8 different descriptions that I want to insert. For example:

```
insert into table (
    p_number, description, period
)
select  p.p_number, g.description, g.period, 
from    other_table p
        ,('desc1' as description
                ,2015 + Level as period
        from dual connect by 2015 + Level <=2050) g
where   p.flag = 'Y';


insert into table (
    p_number, description, period
)
select  p.p_number, g.description, g.period, 
from    other_table p
        ,('desc2' as description
                ,2015 + Level as period
        from dual connect by 2015 + Level <=2050) g
where   p.flag = 'Y';
```

Comment: Into the same table (unclear as you've used a fake and invalid name) but with the rsults of two queries -which you could just union together?  (Maybe with a CTE to remove more duplication.) Why do you want to combine them?

Comment: @AlexPoole there's 8 different descriptions, would doing a "union all" be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CTEs to generate the descriptions and periods, and cross join those to the real source table:

```
insert into target_table (
    p_number, description, period
)
with descriptions (description) as (
            select 'desc1' from dual
  union all select 'desc2' from dual
  -- etc.
),
periods (period) as (
  select 2015 + level
  from dual
  connect by level <= 35
)
select s.p_number, d.description, p.period, 
from source_table s
cross join descriptions d
cross join periods p
where s.flag = 'Y';
```

Untested, of course...

Answer (score 2):

you can use **union all**

```
insert into table (
    p_number, description, period
)
select  p.p_number, g.description, g.period, 
from    other_table p
        ,('desc1' as description
                ,2015 + Level as period
        from dual connect by 2015 + Level <=2050) g
where   p.flag = 'Y'
union all
select  p.p_number, g.description, g.period, 
from    other_table p
        ,('desc2' as description
                ,2015 + Level as period
        from dual connect by 2015 + Level <=2050) g
where   p.flag = 'Y';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use cross joins (and unions):

```
insert into table (
    p_number, description, period
)
select  p.p_number, d.description, g.period
from    other_table p cross join (
    select 'desc1' description from dual  union 
    select 'desc2' from dual  union 
    ...
    select 'desc1' from dual 
) d cross join ( 
    select 2015 + Level as period
        from dual connect by 2015 + Level <=2050
) g
```